# Is it possible to navigate to in-page URL fragment subresources with react-native-render-html as implementing browser behavior?

Tags: html, react-native, href, react-native-render-html

Is it possible to navigate to in-page URL fragment subresources with react-native-render-html as implementing browser behavior? Here is an example. Given this snippet for the html prop:

```
<h1 id="title">The Title</h1>
<div style="width:50px;height:200px;">
...
</div>
<a href="#title">Scroll to The Title</a>
```

When a user presses the "Scroll to The Title" anchor, I would like to contain ScrollView to scroll to "The Title" header.
Linking.openURL is not working can you suggest me the way?

Comment: Welcome [@Krish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14222960/krish)! Just a heads up, Repeating your problem in your question is not necessary. Think of your question as a web page that will reach more users if you try to implement techniques to improve the SEO page rankings for search results.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing this feature is very specific to the underlying HTML structure, so there is not an absolute, generic answer. That is why this feature will not be provided by this library. However, [there is a good step by step guide in this tutorial I wrote](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/blog/2021/06/29/create-blog-app-rnrh-III) for V6.

I'll summarize the important steps below:

1. Thanks to [custom renderers](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/docs/guides/custom-renderers#component-based-custom-rendering), we can map the coordinates of each target with their `id` in a cache object (`Scroller` in the above tutorial) by using [`onLayout` prop](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#onlayout). Beware that those coordinates are relative to the parent `View`.
2. In the same cache object, we store a reference to the underlying `ScrollView`.
3. We define a `scrollToId` method in the cache object, which invokes the underlying `ScrollView` ref [`scrollTo` method](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollto) to scroll to the coordinates we previously mapped to the target.
4. We set the `renderersProps.a.onPress` prop to a callback which will invoke the `scrollToId` method of the cache object.

Note that you'll need to pass the cache object to the custom renderer via [a context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or via [`renderersProps`](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/api/renderhtmlprops#renderersprops) (you can then consume the prop with [`useRendererProp`](https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/api/userendererprops)).

Those steps are freely adapted from the above tutorial and I invite you to dive in to grasp all the implementation details. Good knowledge of React hooks, context and refs is required.